# Responsive button Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am developping an app with angular 8 and I have a form with different buttons. I was wondering if there is any way to make the buttons responsive in phones display with Chrome and Firefox. Here is what I have now :

[image]

My code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-around">
  <button (click)="register()" class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4"> Submiiiiiiiiit </button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-4"> Validate </button>
</div>
```

The display of the first button is down but the second button is OK, the text is what's making the difference I guess.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to set `button{ width: fit-content}` ?? what css do you have on it ?

Comment: I added an Edit with my code

Comment: Your class on 1st button is not closed at the end, it is missing `"`

Comment: Oh yes thank you I added it but it doesn't resolve my problem

Comment: Which bootstrap version do you use 4 ? I edited your post, please accept edit and customized the snipper with container and more details, because just lke this, it seems to work

Comment: Thank you, yes I accepted the edit, I use bootstrap 4.5.0

Comment: are you having this row into a container ? Could you please precise all BS div over to reproduce it. Because like this. it seems to work fine. Check if you dont have an `overflow-wrap: word-break` or somethime like this set your buttons by css

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I added `<meta name="viewport">` in the head and it's now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the unit `vw` for fonts, which correspond to 1% of the width of the viewport.

Here's an example of code:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

And functional example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dve6uw?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: It work with your example @helpmecode https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dve6uw?file=src/app/app.component.css